# How to save canvas with image in fabric

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

i have create one small application for tshirt designing. In which i have drawn the canvas over the image. So user will be restricted to that particular canvas for drawing and editing. So problem is that i want to save the whole image with canvas in it. At present it is only saving the canvas area. Please guide me so i can go further into that.I found few question similar to me but unanswered so i asked it.

[image]

Comment: You could set your canvas to cover the entire area covering the T-Shirt and then make the smaller inner rectangle a clipped area. Example of clipping http://jsfiddle.net/lfergon/ofc0nuau/

Comment: can we set the t-shirt image as background area and cliping rectangle for allow user to modify it ??

Comment: Yes, you really should look at the documentation, it will help :
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#backgroundImage

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/YH9yD/  How to set background

Comment: @DarrylHebbes I know how to add background but wanted to know how make clipped area in canvas which have background image just wanted make sure